# Remove spinner and text view from linear layout on button click one by one from last index

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

[image]Let me explain my issue. I added 4 spinners programmatically by clicking Add button 4 times. Now I'm clicking remove button. It removes only the last spinners .but when i click again gain to remove the spinner and text view it does not remove, i mean nothing happend, Remaining 3 spinners still exist.Now i want when i again click to remove button it remove the spinners from the renaming three n now we have 2 spinners left and so on. Is there anyway to remove?
i will post my code for adding the spinners and removing the spinners 
bt1 button for adding the views programmatically.
bt2 button for removing the views programmatically.
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
           {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                linearlayout1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                linearlayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
                linearlayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );


                tv3 = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tv3.setText("Label");

                tv4 = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv4.setText("Category");




                spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                spinner2 = new Spinner(getActivity());
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

                spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);

                linearlayout1.addView(tv3);
                linearlayout1.addView(spinner);

                linearlayout1.addView(tv4);
                linearlayout1.addView(spinner2);
                linearlayout.addView(linearlayout1);


            }
        });


bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {

                    linearlayout1.removeView(spinner);
                    linearlayout1.removeView(tv3);
                    linearlayout1.removeView(spinner2);
                    linearlayout1.removeView(tv4);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Exception "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are storing only one variable `linearLayout1`. Each time you add a view, the `linearLayout1` is set to the last one. This is why the last one gets deleted but not others..

Update your code to keep a list of layouts as below:

private class field:

```
ArrayList<LinearLayout> rows = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
```

Update your code:

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {

         LinearLayout linearlayout1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            ...
            ...

        linearlayout1.addView(tv4);
        linearlayout1.addView(spinner2);
        linearlayout.addView(linearlayout1);

        // just add this line here. 
        rows.add(linearlayout1); //add layout to the list

    }
});
```

When deleting:

```
bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        try {
            // get the last item
            LinearLayout layoutToRemove = rows.get(rows.size()-1);
            linearlayout.removeView(layoutToRemove); // remove it
            rows.remove(layoutToRemove); // update the list
            linearlayout.invalidate() // may need this (optional)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Exception "+e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you create an array with all your spinner.

If you want to remove your view try this way :

```
((LinearLayout)spinner.getParent()).removeView(spinner);
```

Comment: as i told i am creating spinner dynamically not using xml see in the pic

Comment: If you have your spinner just use this line, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to remove the line, not the views form that line,so what you really need is the getChildCount() method to get the number of the views (lines) of your main linearlayout, and the removeViewAt(int index) with the getChildCount()-1 value, and don't forget to call linearlayout.invalidate()  (main linearlayout) if you didn't enabled animate layout changes